# add commas using String.Format for number and

Tags: c#

Using String.Format how can i ensure all numbers have commas after every 3 digits
eg 23000 = "23,000" and that 0 returns "0".

String.Format("{0:n}", 0); //gives 0.00 which i dont want.
I dont want any decimal places, all numbers will be integers.

Comment: You shouldn't use commas to separate digits, you should use (soft) spaces. Reason is that in a significant part of the world (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.png) the comma is the decimal separator (radix point), and so the meaning of the comma is subjective, context dependent - see Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code commas, but use the locale or internationalization thousands separator.  Use a comma as the default, if you want, when no locale is set.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do this, which I find a bit cleaner to read the intent of:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###0}", 0);
```

Example:

```
string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 123456789); // 123,456,789
string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 0); // 0
```

Comment: This won't necessarily use commas as the thousand separator depending on locale, I believe

Answer (score 27):

If your current culture seting uses commas as thousands separator, you can just format it as a number with zero decimals:

```
String.Format("{0:N0}", 0)
```

Or:

```
0.ToString("N0")
```

Answer (score 4):

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Displays 1,234,567,890

Comment: Beware of this one : it will generate an empty string for value=0 which is certainly what OP wants. Instead, use "#,0" as pattern and it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can also play around a little with the CultureInfo object, if none of the other solutions work well for you:

```
        var x = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        x.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        x.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
        x.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] {3};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a number after the N to specify number of decimal digits:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", 0) // gives 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I up-marked another answer and then found that zero values are an empty string.

```
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

        double x = 23232323.21;
        string y = x.ToString("#,0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The string is returned in the current culture which is German therefore y = 23.232.323

y = 0  when x = 0.

Answer (score 0):

you just put it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(**$**"Your current amount of money is: **{yourVar:c}**");
```

Answer (score 0):

relatively american number to ordinal.

```
using static System.Threading.Thread;

public static string NumberToOrdinal(int number, CultureInfo? culture = null)
{
    var numberString = number.ToString(
        format: "#,0",
        provider: culture ?? CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    // Examine the last 2 digits.
    var lastDigits = number % 100;
    // If the last digits are 11, 12, or 13, use th. Otherwise:
    if (lastDigits is >= 11 and <= 13) return $"{numberString}th";
    // Check the last digit.
    return (lastDigits % 10) switch
    {
        1 => $"{numberString}st",
        2 => $"{numberString}nd",
        3 => $"{numberString}rd",
        _ => $"{numberString}th",
    };
}
```

ps i never comment on these things because stack overflow won't let me and sometimes its not worth upstaging everyone with a new answer for a slight improvement. Screw stackoverflow. I've been here for years and still can't comment- which is why i still don't post.