# Adding comma separators to numbers, asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add comma separators to a number. I've tried the advice here: [add commas using String.Format for number and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545633/add-commas-using-string-format-for-number-and) and here: [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number) but I can't get it to work - they just return the number without commas. The code I'm using is here:

`public static string addCommas(string cash) {
 return string.Format("{0:n0}", cash).ToString();

 }`

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

---

Update: Hi all, thanks for your help, but all of those methods are returning the same error: "error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'BishopFlemingFunctions.addCommas(int)' has some invalid arguments" (or variations therof depending on what number type I'm using.) Any ideas?

Comment: That error message suggests that you are calling the method with an `int` argument, while you showed a `string` argument.

Comment: Hi - yeah, that was after trying the methods below, not with my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are sending in a string. it looks like you want a currency back

1. Why are you passing in a string to the method if it is a numeric value?
2. String.Format will return a string so there is not need to .ToString() it again.
3. {0:c} = Currency format if you do not want the $ then use {0:n}
4. Not sure you have to but you may need to do an explicit conversion if you pass it in as a string to (decimal)cash

return String.Format("{0:c}", (decimal)cash);

or

return String.Format("{0:n}", (decimal)cash);

but i think it should be something like:

```
public static string addCommas(decimal cash)
{
return String.Format("{0:c}", cash);
}
```

but this is such a simple statement i do not see the logic in making it a method, if you method is one line, in most cases, its not a method.

Comment: you can't cast a string to a decimal, you need Convert.ToDecimal or Decimal.Parse (or TryParse).

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply number formatting you have to pass `cash` as a number type (int, double, float etc)

Answer (score 0):

Note the cash parameter is of type `double` and the `.##` at the end of the formatted string for cents.

**EDIT**

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        double d = 123456789.7845;
        string s = addCommas(d);
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static string addCommas(double cash) {
        return string.Format("${0:#,###0.##}", cash);
    }
}
```

This prints "$123,456,789.78" to console. If you're getting

> error CS1502: The best overloaded
>   method match for 'addCommas(double)'
>   has some invalid arguments

check to make sure that you're calling the function properly and that you're actually passing in the correct data type. I encourage you to copy/paste the code I have above and run it - BY ITSELF.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help, but all of those methods are returning the same error: "error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'BishopFlemingFunctions.addCommas(int)' has some invalid arguments" (or variations therof depending on what number type I'm using.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i have a method on my custom class to convert any numbers

```
public static string ConvertToThosandSepratedNumber(object number)
{
    string retValue = "";
    retValue = string.Format("{0:N0}", Convert.ToDecimal(number));
    return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly efficient way to Add commas for thousands place, etc.
It is written in VB.net.
It does not work for negative numbers.

```
Public Function AddCommas(number As Integer) As String
    Dim s As String = number.ToString()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(16)
    Dim countHead As Integer = s.Length Mod 3
    If countHead = 0 Then countHead = 3
    sb.Append(s.Substring(0, countHead))

    For I As Integer = countHead To s.Length - 1 Step 3
        sb.Append(","c)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(I, 3))
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```