# Add commas in decimal to string

Tags: c#, .net, string, decimal

I want to add a comma in the decimal to string conversion like

For

```
decimal number = 1000000000.000;
```

it should give

```
string str = 1,00,00,00,000.00
```

Comment: really `1,00,00,00,000.00`? or did you mean `1,000,000,000.00`? In that case the formatstring would be `#,#.00`

Comment: possible duplicate of [add commas using String.Format for number and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545633/add-commas-using-string-format-for-number-and)

Comment: Which culture uses this format?

Comment: @StephanBauer Bauer I really mean `1,00,00,00,000.00` this formatting is used in India

Comment: @RohitChaudhari Nice, I didn't know that :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12492567/314334

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can use some **predefined culture**, but I would like to introduce this way, with `NumberGroupSizes` to specify whatever format you want:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Console.WriteLine("{0:#,#.00}", 12345678.12);
//output 
1,23,45,678.12
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] {4, 2};
//output
12,34,5678.12
//....
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by using the correct [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx):

```
decimal input = 1000000000.0000m;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
string output = string.Format(ci,"{0:#,#.00}",input);
```

By the way: following `CultureInfos` produce the correct output:

```
hi,bn,pa,gu,or,ta,te,kn,ml,as,mr,sa,kok,si,ne,
hi-IN,bn-IN,pa-IN,gu-IN,or-IN,ta-IN,te-IN,kn-IN,
ml-IN,as-IN,mr-IN,sa-IN,kok-IN,si-LK,ne-NP,bn-BD,en-IN
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP wants. `+1`

Comment: @Stephan Bauer This is good research but I would like to implement King King's answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx

```
specifier = "#,#.00#;(#,#.00#)";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, (value*-1).ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    #,#.00#;(#,#.00#): (16,325.62)
```

Comment: what is `value`? is it better to just write `-value` instead of `value*-1`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this,

```
String.Format("{0:#,###0}", 0);
```